# How do I use loops in Oz?

Tags: oz, mozart

From this documentation: http://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/loop/node1.html

I get the basic loop usage for iteration:

```
for X in SomeList do
   % ...
end
```

And numbers:

```
for X in x..y do
   % ...
end
```

But the "features" that are explained has no examples. It just says that you break by "break:B" and continue by "continue:C" but it gives no examples of how to use this in actual code. I assumed this was meant:

```
local X in
   break:X

   for Y in 1..5 do
      {Browse Y}

      if Y > 3 then {X} end
   end
end
```

But `break:X` is not a valid statement.

Could somebody please give me some examples of how to use features like "break:B" and "while:E".

---

Failed attempt after comment from wmeyer:

```
local X in
   X = {NewCell [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]}
   for while:@X\=nil do
      {Browse @X.1}
      @X := @X.2
   end
end
```

Parse error on the `for ...` line. How do I use the `while` feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop "features" must be specified in the for-loop itself.

```
for Y in 1..5 break:X do
    {X}
end
```

(As far as I remember. I did not test this.)

Comment: Thanks. That got `break` and `continue` working, but I still can't get `while` or `until` to work (see update)

Comment: I think the problem is with the not-equal operator you are trying to use. It should be `\=` in Oz.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! Any idea why the loop still just prints 1 then exits?

Comment: When assigning to a cell, you don't need the `@` on the left side. Just `X := @X.2`.

Comment: Whoops, typo... Thanks